# HIbernate - Many to Many - Nested c:foreach

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm trying to run a nested `c:loop` in the following. Before the page loads, i get a list `itemsextrascat` objects with `itemsextrascatService.getExtrascatByIditems(item)`. No problem here, i get the right number of results. However, the nested loop is not displaying properly. Not sure if its a hibernate issue or jstl.

jsp

```
<c:forEach var="itemsextrascat" items="${itemsextrascat}">
    <th><c:out value="${itemsextrascat.extrascat.name}"></c:out> </th><br>
    <table> 
        <c:forEach var="extras" items="${itemsextrascat.extrascat.extras}">
            <tr><c:out value="${extras.name}"></c:out></tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

which returns

```
Fruit 
Overy Easy

Syrups 
Over Medium

Breakfast Additions 
Sunny Side Up
```

So the category titles are correct, however the extras are 1) incorrect for the item and extrascat and 2) they are not all listing all extras under the category. Pretty sure its how hibernate is calling the object but I'm at a loss.

Extrascat.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extrascat")
public class Extrascat implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8644201177004602944L;

    @Id
    private int idextrascat;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "extrascat")
    private Set<Items> items = new HashSet<Items>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idextras")
    private Set<Extras> extras;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Extrascat() {

    }

    public Extrascat(int idextrascat, String name, Set<Items> items, Set<Extras> extras) {
        this.idextrascat = idextrascat;
        this.name = name;
        this.items = items;
        this.extras = extras;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public int getIdextrascat() {
        return idextrascat;
    }

    public void setIdextrascat(int idextrascat) {
        this.idextrascat = idextrascat;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Set<Items> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Set<Extras> getExtras() {
        return extras;
    }

    public void setExtras(Set<Extras> extras) {
        this.extras = extras;
    }

}
```

Items.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3607451001182083512L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int iditems;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcategories")
    private Categories categories;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 35, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class,
            FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 0, max = 100, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class,
            FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String description;

    private double priceInCents;
    private int hidden;

    @OrderColumn
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="itemsextrascat", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="iditems")}, 
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idextrascat")})
    private Set<Extrascat> extrascat = new HashSet<Extrascat>();

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Items() {

    }

    public Items(int iditems, Categories categories, String name, String description, double priceInCents, int hidden, Set<Extrascat> extrascat) {
        this.iditems = iditems;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
        this.hidden = hidden;
        this.extrascat = extrascat;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public int getIditems() {
        return iditems;
    }

    public void setIditems(int iditems) {
        this.iditems = iditems;
    }

    public Categories getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Categories categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getPriceInCents() {
        return priceInCents;
    }

    public void setPriceInCents(double priceInCents) {
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
    }

    public int isHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }

    public void setHidden(int hidden) {
        this.hidden = hidden;
    }

    public Set<Extrascat> getExtrascat() {
        return extrascat;
    }

    public void setExtrascat(Set<Extrascat> extrascat) {
        this.extrascat = extrascat;
    }

    public int getHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }

}
```

Itemsextrascat.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "itemsextrascat")
public class Itemsextrascat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7640244484584804821L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int iditemsextrascat;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "iditems")
    private Items items;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idextrascat")
    private Extrascat extrascat;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Itemsextrascat() {

    }

    public Itemsextrascat(int iditemsextrascat, Items items, Extrascat extrascat) {
        this.iditemsextrascat = iditemsextrascat;
        this.items = items;
        this.extrascat = extrascat;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public int getIditemsextrascat() {
        return iditemsextrascat;
    }

    public void setIditemsextrascat(int iditemsextrascat) {
        this.iditemsextrascat = iditemsextrascat;
    }

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Extrascat getExtrascat() {
        return extrascat;
    }

    public void setExtrascat(Extrascat extrascat) {
        this.extrascat = extrascat;
    }

}
```

Extras.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extras")
public class Extras implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8644201177004602944L;

    @Id
    private int idextras;
    private String name;
    private double priceincents;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idextrascat")
    private Extrascat extrascat;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "extras")
    private Set<Orderitem> orderitem = new HashSet<Orderitem>();

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Extras() {

    }

    public Extras(int idextras, String name, double priceincents, Extrascat extrascat) {
        this.idextras = idextras;
        this.name = name;
        this.priceincents = priceincents;
        this.extrascat = extrascat;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public int getIdextras() {
        return idextras;
    }

    public void setIdextras(int idextras) {
        this.idextras = idextras;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPriceincents() {
        return priceincents;
    }

    public void setPriceincents(double priceincents) {
        this.priceincents = priceincents;
    }

    public Extrascat getExtrascat() {
        return extrascat;
    }

    public void setExtrascat(Extrascat extrascat) {
        this.extrascat = extrascat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I remove the itemsextrascat.java along with the service and Dao and query either items or extras for the c:foreach

Comment: Its good practice to create different beans for UI. Entity beans are meant for backend logic processing.

Comment: Start by generating valid HTML. You can't have text directly inside a tr. th mudt be contained in tr, and td too. Test must be inside th or td, but not directly in tr. Don't use the same variable name (itemsextrascat) for two different things. Don't use the plural form (extras, items, etc.) to refer to a single thing (one extra).

Comment: Did as Zaki said and created a bean to handle the object for the UI. It's now working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zaki was correct to suggest creating a new bean for the UI. I was querying one table and expecting to get results from multiple tables. Instead, I populate a new object that holds the values I need and use that object in my view.